# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy only in First Launch

Tags: swift, uialertview

I have an Onboarding screen that I'm showing to the new users when they first open the app.
In my appDelegate I check whether is the first launch or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OnBoarding")


        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "onBoardingComplete") {
            initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainApp")

        }
        window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Also I have a collectionViewCell that I have some buttons and when I click them I get an Alert with informations.

**Example of one button**

```
@IBAction func guide3Btn(_ sender: Any) {
        let infoVC = infoService.info(title: "Title", body: "Information")

        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(infoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

When the user first launches the app if he clicks the info button gets this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MyApp.InfoViewController:      0x7f91db45cfb0> on <MyApp.OnbBoardViewController: 0x7f91db506af0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

If the user reopens the app everything is ok. I know that when we have first launch we have onBoarding as root controller but I can't understand how to fix this.

**Update**

This is the infoService class. I use a new storyboard to create the alert.

```
class InfoService {

    func info(title: String, body: String) -> InfoViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "InfoStoryboard", bundle: .main)

        let infoVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoVC") as! InfoViewController

        infoVC.infoBody = body
        infoVC.infoTitle = title

        return infoVC
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's `self.window` come from ?

Comment: I present it from a collectionViewCell class so I need a ViewController.

Comment: I mean how you define  the window you're using in the function `guide3Btn `

Comment: I update my question with the infoService class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add your storyboard instantiate code blocks to main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async` like below:

I solved almost all of my `whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` problems.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let infoVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoVC") as! InfoViewController

    infoVC.infoBody = body
    infoVC.infoTitle = title
}
    return infoVC
```

Referenced from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126338/4442254

Comment: You can not return anything from inside closure. Compile your code first before posting an answer.